# Git impossible to discard permissions changes in WSL2

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I using docker so I recently placed my workspace in WSL2 ubuntu-20.04 filesystem to get better performance with docker. But I have a problem when I clone the project. I have 7 `.sh` files who have been change because they have 755 permissions and I don't know why but WSL2 force to use the permission 644. If I discard local changes there is no effect it will set my files with 644 permission.

I tried to use `git rm --cached -r .` + `git reset --hard` but there is no effect too.

The only thing that I can do is to disable the permission tracking with `git config core.filemode false`. If I don't do that I'll get this push on my remote :

[image: push permission]

I don't understand why I have this behavior on WSL2 because if I place my project in windows I don't have this problem and on my other computer running on Linux manjaro I don't have the problem too.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: How did you create the repository within the WSL instance? What file system type does the working tree use?

Comment: @torek I created the repo with `git clone` inside /home/user. I don't know what is the file system type I just installed wsl ubuntu-20.04

Comment: OK - when you run `git clone` (or `git init`), Git tests out the system to see if `chmod` operations actually work. It then sets `core.filemode` accordingly. So core.filemode *should* reflect how WSL is actually treating `chmod` calls, but from the problem you're experiencing, it seems like `core.filemode` *isn't* doing that, which indicates that either WSL is inconsistent, or the clone had been made in one system and then used in another, e.g., made in WSL but then used in Windows. Beyond that, I don't know what else to check.

Comment: @torek ok. Hmm it's weird because I do the clone only inside WSL and I did it multiple times to test. I noticed something. To allow git ssh connection I have to create my ssh-keygen inside windows in `c:/user/.ssh/` the connection is not working if I place my keys inside WSL .ssh folders. Maybe this is the problem ?